# Javascript/Html ReplaceChild Url btn

Tags: javascript, html

The code can be viewed at:

```
                 http://fxv4.com/js/java.html
```

(source: view-source:http://fxv4.com/js/java.html )

And the problem is that the code inside the  does not change the url.
The problem is not big but if you remove the  tag the function does not work. Neither the countdown.
What i simply want is is for the url inside js btn to be stealth as a normal submit / js btn.

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Your content is inside the <head>

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider posting a condensed form of your problem and code, this way people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

That your current code:

```
<a href="http://fxv4.com/js/java.html" id="download" class="button"> 
  <button onclick="window.location='http://URL undefined';">Visit Page Now</button>
</a>
```

Add to button onclick return statement false, so click event won`t be send to parent element:

```
<a href="http://fxv4.com/js/java.html" id="download" class="button"> 
  <button onclick="window.location='http://URL undefined';return false">Visit Page Now</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to rearrange your code and know the fundamentals of HTML/JS. Keep in mind the following:

1. You should only place HTML elements inside the `<body>`, no inside `head`.
2. JavaScript code that alter HTML elements has to be executed after the DOM document has loaded.

Example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // (2) Run JavaScript after DOM document has loaded.

      window.onload = function() {

          var message = document.getElementById('message');
          var button = document.getElementById('button');
          var counter = 5;

          var interval = setInterval(function() {
              if (counter === 0) {
                  button.style.display = 'block';
                  message.style.display = 'none';
                  clearInterval(interval);
              }
              message.innerHTML = 'You can view the url in ' + (counter--) + ' seconds.';
          }, 1000);

          button.onclick = function() {
              window.location = 'http://google.ch/';
          };

      };​

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      button { display:none; }​
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- (1) HTML element live inside the body. -->
    <span id="message">...</span>
    <button id="button">Visit Page Now</button>​
  </body>
</html>
```